# Pending intent with different intent but same ID

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I have two pending Intent to use with Alarm Manager one is:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, TriggerAlarm.class);  
PendingIntent pi =PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

and the other is:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(context, TriggerNotification.class);
 PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0, i,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

I use these two in different methods in my application

my question is:

Are these pendingIntents differnt from each other?? because the intents are    different but the Ids are same

If I set alarm manager for each of these pending intent do both of them trigger or one replace another?

Comment: You can have same ids for multiple instances in different methods, as the scope of each id will be the method body only, but when you accessing it out side then it will depends on runtime accessibility as which instance system call and accordingly it will execute the next task

Comment: you mean they are different?

Comment: drom the docs: `The parts of the Intent that are used for matching are the same ones defined by Intent.filterEquals. If you use two Intent objects that are equivalent as per Intent.filterEquals, then you will get the same PendingIntent for both of them.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the easy way is test it directly by yourself.
I have tested it on my computer and here is what i got:

Are these pendingIntents different from each other?? because the intents are different but the Ids are same

**-Yes they are different each other although the Ids are same**

If I set alarm manager for each of these pending intent do both of them trigger or one replace another?

**-Both of them will be triggered**

Here are my code for test, you can copy and try it by yourself

Copy this method to your activity, and call it

```
private void setAlarmManager() {
    Log.v("AlarmManager", "Configuring AlarmManager...");
    Intent startIntent1 = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiverFirst.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, startIntent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    Intent startIntent2 = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiverSecond.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, startIntent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 20);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Log.v("AlarmManager", "Starting AlarmManager for >= KITKAT version");
        alarm.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent1);
        alarm.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent2);
    } else {
        Log.v("AlarmManager", "Starting AlarmManager for < KITKAT version");
        alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent1);
        alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent2);
    }

    Log.v("AlarmManager", "AlarmManager has been started");
}
```

Create your first receiver class

```
public class AlarmReceiverFirst extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "first alarm receiver is called");
    }
}
```

Create your second receiver class

```
public class AlarmReceiverSecond extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "second alarm receiver is called");
    }
}
```

Register those receivers to your manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiverFirst" />
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiverSecond" />
```

Not to be confused, what you called Id here is called request code. It is used for cancelling the pending intent.

Comment: thanks for your response,I tested by myself too but I wanted a certain and sure answer thanks anyway

Comment: what if I use only single AlarmReceiver class for this case?

Comment: @JimmyTrivedi Yes you can use only single `AlarmReceiver` class for different `PendingIntent`s, but make sure the request code is unique, so each `PendingIntent` will always call the AlarmReceiver class. Otherwise the `AlarmReceiver` class only called once.

Comment: @HendraWD That is the issue. I want to do for same ID

Comment: @JimmyTrivedi If you want each `PendingIntent` you create will always call the `AlarmReceiver`, use different request codes. Otherwise use the same request code, it will overrides the previous `PendingIntent` with the same request code. I hope my explanation is clear enough.

Answer (score 3):

Intents are just the action PendingIntent is bound to execute once it triggers. But this triggering criteria are entirely depending on PendingIntent itself and RequestCode is playing here a pretty good role to uniquely identify, manage and trigger PendingIntent.

Therefore, no matter what the Intent is, if the requestCode is repeated then the latter PendingIntent will trigger. If you need to trigger multiple PendingIntents, the requestCode must be different from each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can have same name of intents but with different ids like following,

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, TriggerAlarm.class);  
PendingIntent pi =PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,System.currentTimeMillis(),i,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

And

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, TriggerNotification.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,System.currentTimeMillis(), i,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

This way both the intents would be distinguished differently from each other and will get triggered.You can have any unique id instead of `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Comment: In my case I have two table database one for alarms and the other for notifications and I use each id (Auto Increment)  for pending Intent's Id and maybe the ids conflict each other !!! because of two table