# How to know that my scheduled alarm has been canceled in AlarmManager using cancelAlarm method in Android?

Tags: android

Is there any way that I can print Log and check it?
like I tried this code:

```
  if (mPendingIntent == null) {
            showLog("cancelAlarm(): canceled");
        } else {
            showLog("cancelAlarm(): Unable to cancel scheduled alarms");
        }
```

But, I don't think that mPendingIntent will be null!
Note: I'm using same Id, to create & cancel alarms.

```
public void cancelAlarm(Context context, int ID) {
        AlarmManager mAlarmManager;
        mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ID, new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class), 0);
        mAlarmManager.cancel(mPendingIntent);

        // Restart alarm if device is rebooted
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
```

//For Create

```
public void createRepeatAlarm(Context context, Calendar calendar, int id, long repeatTime) {
        AlarmManager mAlarmManager;
        mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra(REMINDER_ID, id);

        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), repeatTime, mPendingIntent);

        /*TODO:-> Restart alarm if device is rebooted*/
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
```

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: please explain what you want to achieve. it is unclear from your question.

Comment: @HarshShah I sat some alarms in my alarm manager using above create method. Now I call cancel method from onReceive so that my all future alarms will be canceled associated with same Id. But still I have doubt that alarm is not canceled. So I want to check it. How can I do that?

Comment: there is no method to check if the alarm is canceled or not.

You can get only get last alarm value from the alarm manager.

You need to generate the same intent and call alarmManager.cancel(broadcast); method. it should work.

If you are deleting all the notifications then you can check if alarm manager not returning any value then you have deleted all the alarms.

Comment: @HarshShah Can you please explain through code?

Comment: @HarshShah I'll accept your answer if it works.

Comment: @HarshShah Also, help me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38758424/pending-intent-with-different-intent-but-same-id In that accepted answer, what if I'll create only single class?